# How to disable a specific input text acording to the dropbox selection?

Tags: php, javascript, drop-down-menu

```
<?php    
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript"><!--
    function codename() {
        if(document.Tipo.Tipo.value="1"){
            document.formname.nome.disabled="disable";
        }
        else {
            document.formname.nome.disabled="enable";
        }
    }
//-->
</SCRIPT>

<html>
<body>
    <form action ="registoDois.php" Method="post" align="center" name="formname">
    <table align="center">
            <td class="float-right">Tipo de conta:</label></td>
            <td>

            <select name="Tipo" id="Tipo">
                <option value="">Tipo:</option>
                <option value="1">Aluno</option>
                <option value="2">Professor</option>
                <option value="3">Admin</option>
            </select>


        <tr>
            <td class="float-right">Nome:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" placeholder="Bruno" id="firstname" name="nome"  /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</html>
</body>

?>
```

I have a dropbox and an input text in a form that should disable according to the selection in the dropbox. For example if the user selects "`Aluno`" with the value "`1`" the javascript should disable the input text "`name`" from user input, but if the user selects another option from the dropbox the input text name is enabled.

Comment: What is the error you getting

Comment: Added a jsfiddle of a working version to my answer. That should get you going..

Comment: @user2451445 Don't forget to accept the answer that helped you with your question by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an onchange to the select box..

```
<select name="Tipo" id="Tipo" onchange="codename();">
    <option value="">Tipo:</option>
    <option value="1">Aluno</option>
    <option value="2">Professor</option>
    <option value="3">Admin</option>
</select>
```

And you are missing `<label>` tags, `<tr>` tags and more. You really need to make sure your html is valid before adding javascript and what not..

Check this jsfiddle for a working version of your html and javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/dovereem/L7wsa/2/

Comment: Thanks for everything. That file clarified me. That missing <label> and <tr> was accidental deleted when I copy pasted the code here. I'm still learning JavaScript and I'm new to this community but once again thanks!